# Magento 2 : what is difference between js Merge and Bundling

Tags: magento2, javascript

What kind of difference between js Merge and js Bundling for speed optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Minifying is removing unneeded white spaces and newlines, bundling is merging together various resources in one

In terms of speed optimization both techniques should (in theory) improve speed as they are supposed to reduce file size and requests made to the server

The detailed differences between merging/bundling are explained here: 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html#magento-merging-and-bundling

Basically merging creates only one js file while bundling splits the js resources into different bundles (they can't both work at the same time), this is also useful: 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html

Comment: I have updated my question.